# Как передать параметры в скрипт в при запуске SlimerJS?

Tags: phantomjs

Есть скрипт на **PHP** который запускает **SlimerJS**.

Как мне в **script.js** передать аргумент: `$arg = "qwertyui";` ?

**Вырезка из скрипта:** `exec('C:\SlimerJS\bin\slimerjs script.js');`

Comment: `exec('C:\SlimerJS\bin\slimerjs script.js ' . $arg);` - ?

Comment: Ну это уж было бы совсем просто. По документации в "SlimerJS" идет var system = require('system'), var thirdArgument = system.args[2]; Но как передать аргумент и вывести его в "script.js"

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function run() {
    $script = __DIR__.'\slimer.js';
    $slimerjs = 'C:\WebLib\Slimerjs\slimerjs';
    $args = 'dasdasasd';

    shell_exec("{$slimerjs} {$script} {$args}");
}
```

Аргументы оказывается передавались, это я не правильно их принимал

```
var system = require("system");
var args = system.args[1];

page.open("site ulr", function (status) {
page.evaluate(function (args) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('blockbg')[1].textContent = args;
}, args);});
```